# Using libcurl with threaded resolver and CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL together on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, libcurl

I am using libcurl 7.72.0 in a multithreaded C++ application on Linux. For each curl handle (using curl_easy_perform), I set `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL = 1L` before. The library was built with `ENABLE_THREADED_RESOLVER` and not with C-Ares.

At the end of the cmake-output, the following is shown:

```
-- Enabled features: SSL IPv6 unix-sockets libz AsynchDNS NTLM HTTPS-proxy
-- Enabled protocols: DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP
-- Enabled SSL backends: OpenSSL
```

My question is whether it is okay to have the asynchronous `THREADED_RESOLVER` enabled and still use `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL = 1L`. I want to ensure that the configuration is multithreading safe and that the timeouts are triggered, so I tend to have both options enabled. I have tested it with a fictional URL like `www.erfunden.de`, and it seems that the timeout still works.